# Find string in xml and get the corresponding sister(?) nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I am making a tool which reads the cvc of a file, and searches the cvc value in an xml. it has multiple parent notes called release. i already managed to let it find the cvc value in the xml but i am not able to make it, that it gets the corresponding sister(sorry i dont know how its called) nodes.
This is a part of the XML:

```
<releases>
    <release>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>name1</name>
        <publisher></publisher>
        <region>WLD</region>
        <languages>en,fr,de,it,es,ru,ja</languages>
        <group></group>
        <imagesize>16</imagesize>
        <serial>LA-H-AAAAA</serial>
        <titleid>01007EF00011E000 </titleid>
        <imgcrc>5DD119C1</imgcrc>
        <filename>test</filename>
        <releasename>test</releasename>
        <trimmedsize>0</trimmedsize>
        <firmware>1.0.0</firmware>
        <type>1</type>
        <card>1</card>
    </release>
    <release>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>name2</name>
        <publisher></publisher>
        <region>WLD</region>
        <languages>en,fr,de,it,es,nl,pt,ru,ja</languages>
        <group></group>
        <imagesize>8</imagesize>
        <serial>LA-H-AABPA</serial>
        <titleid>0100152000022000</titleid>
        <imgcrc>1912A1DF</imgcrc>
        <filename>test</filename>
        <releasename>test</releasename>
        <trimmedsize>0</trimmedsize>
        <firmware>1.0.0</firmware>
        <type>1</type>
        <card>1</card>
    </release>
```

This is my code:

```
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode ("releases/*[contains(name(),'release')]/imgcrc[text() = '" + textBox6.Text + "']");
if (node == null)
{
    XmlNode id = node.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode ("titleid");
    XmlNode serial = node.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode ("serial");
    XmlNode r = node.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode ("region");
    XmlNode fw = node.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode ("firmware");

    textBox8.Text = id.InnerText;
    textBox4.Text = r.InnerText;
    if (textBox4.Text == "WLD") {
        textBox4.Text = "Worldwide";
    }
    textBox3.Text = fw.InnerText;
    if (textBox3.Text == "") {
        textBox3.Text = "The required FW wasn't found yet";
    }
    textBox2.Text = serial.InnerText;
} else {
    textBox2.Text = "Game is not in the DB or you modified it";
    textBox3.Text = "Game is not in the DB or you modified it";
    textBox4.Text = "Game is not in the DB or you modified it";
    textBox8.Text = "Game is not in the DB or you modified it";
}
```

Sorry if my question isnt clear enough and or the formating wrong.

Comment: read twice and couldn't understand what is the problem? If you can find firmware and serial why you can't find crc?

Comment: my problem is not the crc. i cant get the fw, region, serial and id

Comment: May be, get the parent node of founded node and then get childs of this parent node?

Comment: Your `if` statement is back to front, this code will only throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a path something like this, you will get the `release` element rather than just the `imgcrc` element:

```
var path = "releases/release[imgcrc = '"+ crc +"']";
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(path);
```

Now you can grab the relevant child values from there:

```
if(node != null)
{
    var titleId = node["titleid"].InnerText;
    var serial = node["serial"].InnerText;
    var region = node["region"].InnerText;
    var firmware = node["firmware"].InnerText;

    //etc
}
```

Comment: I tried it, sadly it doesnt give me anything, even tho the crc is in the xml. if i make the if(node != null) to if(node == null) it errors out

Comment: *"doesn't give me anything"* what does that mean? I have tested this code with the XML you provide and it works fine.

Comment: i made it that it shall show the var titleId in a messagebox, which was blank.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with that code, or the text box is being cleared. Either way, it's outide of the code I show here.

Comment: i added a else statement now which shall say no if it isnt found in the node, and it doesnt find the crc. is the searching case sensitive?

Comment: yep, found the issue, it is case sensitive

Comment: Yes, it is case sensitive, simply to `crc.ToUpper()`

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("release").Select(x => new {
                        id = (int)x.Element("id"),
                        name = (string)x.Element("name"),
                        publisher = (string)x.Element("publisher"),
                        region = (string)x.Element("region"),
                        languages = (string)x.Element("languages"),
                        group = (string)x.Element("group"),
                        imagesize = (int)x.Element("imagesize"),
                        serial = (string)x.Element("serial"),
                        titleid = (string)x.Element("titleid"),
                        imgcrc = (string)x.Element("imgcrc"),
                        filename = (string)x.Element("filename"),
                        releasename= (string)x.Element("releasename"),
                        trimmedsize = (int)x.Element("trimmedsize"),
                        firmware = (string)x.Element("firmware"),
                        type = (int)x.Element("type"),
                        card = (int)x.Element("card")
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```